# Auto height div Not working

Tags: html, css, web

I'm trying to make the height of a div auto size depending on its contents:

```
 <div id = "bar2">
      <div id = "breadcrumbs"><p>Home &nbsp;>&nbsp; About</p></div>   
      <div id = "anterialtitle"><h1>About</h1></div>
      <div id = "rightblockant"><img src = "img/about.jpg" alt = "About Image | Alternative Text" width = "300" height = "200"/><p class = "firstpara">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat. Ut wisi enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exerci tation ullamcorper suscipit lobortis nisl ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p><br/></div>
      <div id = "leftblockant"><p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat. Ut wisi enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exerci tation ullamcorper suscipit lobortis nisl ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis autem vel eum iriure dolor in hendrerit in vulputate velit esse molestie consequat, vel illum dolore eu feugiat nulla facilisis at vero eros et accumsan</p></div>
      </div>
      </div>
    <div id="footer">
                <p><a href ="">About</a>&nbsp;|&nbsp;<a href = "">Contact Us</a>&nbsp;|&nbsp;<a href = "">Shipping Information</a>&nbsp;|&nbsp;<a href = "">Returns Policy</a>&nbsp;|&nbsp;<a href = "">Terms & Conditions</a>&nbsp;|&nbsp;<a href = "">Privacy Policy</a></p>
            <p>&copy; 2011 <a href="" target="_blank">Everry London</a>. All rights reserved.</p>
        </div>



#bar2{  
    width:960px;
    height: auto;
    position:relative;
    margin:0 auto;
    border-left:1px solid #cccccc;
    border-right:1px solid #cccccc;
    border-bottom:1px solid #cccccc;
    border-top:5px solid #313131;
    margin-top:15px;
    margin-left:4px;    
}
```

However, this is the result:

www.everry.com/new/home/about.html

It only encapsulates the h1 and not the img or the p tags..why is this?

Answer (score 1):

you close one div to much

> ```
>   <div id = "leftblockant"><p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat. Ut wisi enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exerci tation ullamcorper suscipit lobortis nisl ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis autem vel eum iriure dolor in hendrerit in vulputate velit esse molestie consequat, vel illum dolore eu feugiat nulla facilisis at vero eros et accumsan</p></div>
>   </div>
>   </div>
> ```

edit:  sorry i saw now your webpage this is for the header div i'm sorry

Answer (score 0):

Floats. When you float content inside a div and you don't "clear" it it will do that.

You can fix this with adding a div element at the end of the floated elements with `clear:both` or you can add `overflow: hidden` to `.bar2`.

I suggest you also search for clearfix on Google for a better solution.

Answer (score 0):

try `float:left;` for the ID 'bar2'

Comment: float takes the elements out of the normal page flow.